# Send "Open Text Exceed 14" to Windows system tray

Tags: windows, system-tray, exceed

does anybody know how i send the "Open Text Exceed 14" Application to the Windows System Tray? I don't want to keep it all the time in my taskbar.

Regards
Quast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

W7 : put the pointer on the exceed taskbar icon, wait for the upper bubble then move pointer on it, right click Tools / Hide Main Icon.
[see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYoVp.png)